# ehCache not working in hudson

Tags: web-applications, jenkins, hudson, ehcache

I'm developing a java webapp using spring mvc and **ehCache**. I can deploy it fine using tomcat, or jetty. I have 2 maven projects, a webapp/war and an integration test. I want the hudson job to run the integration-tests after starting the webapp as part of the integration-test lifecycle.

However, when I try to start it up as part of a hudson job, I get an exception saying

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.ehcache.Cache.getAll(Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/util/Map;
```

My integration test POM has the follolwing:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
      <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <container>
          <containerId>jetty7x</containerId>
          <type>embedded</type>
        </container>
        <configuration>
          <type>standalone</type>
          <properties>
            <cargo.servlet.port>8040</cargo.servlet.port>
          </properties>
          <deployables>
            <deployable>
              <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
              <artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
              <type>war</type>
              <pingURL>http://localhost:8040/context/status</pingURL>
              <properties>
                <context>context</context>
              </properties>
            </deployable>
          </deployables>
        </configuration>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>start-server</id>
          <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>start</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>stop-server</id>
          <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>stop</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
          <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
          <version>2.12</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <configuration></configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.class</include>
            </includes>
            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>verify</id>
          <goals>
            <goal>verify</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And the line of code that fails:

```
@Named("statGroupDto")
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CachedStatGroupDaoImpl implements StatGroupDao {
  @Inject
  public CachedStatGroupDaoImpl(@Named("cacheManager") final org.springframework.cache.CacheManager cacheManager) {
    this.cacheManager = (EhCacheCacheManager) cacheManager;
 statsGroupCacheCache =  (EhCacheCache) this.cacheManager.getCache("statsCache");
            statsGroupCache = (Cache) statsGroupCacheCache.getNativeCache();
    @Override
    public Collection<StatGroup> getAll() {
      Map<Object, Element> allElements = statsGroupCache.getAll(statsGroupCache.getKeys());
```

It starts and runs fine on my dev machine, and in production, but when hudson trys to run the integration tests, it cannot start the web service.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SInce hudson was running in Jetty, I suspect it was using the wrong class.
See the disadvantages section of http://cargo.codehaus.org/Embedded+Container